# integration tests, can't return an array NodeJS/Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Hey I want return an array in integration tests,

I have a function in which tables are retrieved. Function expect object `req.user._id`, so I create it, next I create integration test, but when i run I have return empty object, could someone tell me what I have to do to get returned array?

function :

```
 .get('/boards-list', function (req, res) {
    Board.find({ 'users': req.user._id })
      .then((board) => {
        res.json(board);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(404).json('Nie można pobrać tablic.')
      })
  })
```

mocha :

```
describe('/boards-list', () => {
  it('it should GET all the boards', (done) => {
    var req = {};
    req.user = {};
     req.user._id = "ObjectId('5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c')";


    chai.request(server)
        .get('/boards-list')
        .send(req)
        .end((err, res) => { 
          console.log(res.body);
                        // res.should.have.status(200);
                        // res.body.should.be.a('array');
                        // res.body.length.should.be.eql(0);
          done();
        });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the id you are passing:

```
req.user._id = "ObjectId('5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c')";
```

Try to pass it like this:

```
req.user._id = "5a8db5d449c0572dbc60548c";
```

Comment: still is returned empty object

Comment: its returning as req.body.req.user._id how can I make local variable req.user._id and pass it to function?

Comment: hehe in this case is get :D

Comment: kgangadhar could u tell me, how can I make test on .post if I need authentication (be login in) ?

Comment: check what and all you need to pass while calling the endpoint, pass those parameter through body or header.

Comment: could u give me example?